# .sql file in eclipse, show it as a table?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, eclipse

In my app I want a small database (.sql), with data about energy (kCal) in food.

The problem is, I have a bit expertise with SQL, but I don't really get my database into my app. Do I have to make a new .java file? Or I've read somewhere else, in my assets? I think the database isn't on a server, just within the app. The project I already have, is an about about food, overweight and BMI. Now I want to add a database about the amount of kCal in food.

I do not really know what I have to say more here. Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do. I've read ALL related questions here on Stackoverflow, but still didn't got an answer.

If you can help me, you would be my hero! :)

Thank you all in advance,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Android's built-in on-device DBMS is not mysql, but SQLite. You can find an excellent tutorial on setting it up and integrating it into your app [here.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create the SQLite database file with whatever data you want in it on your PC.  Then create an assets folder in your project root in Eclipse (same level as src/, bin/, libs/, res/, etc.).  Put your SQLite file in there.  Then write some code to copy that asset file into the correct location on the device.  Following is the code I currently use for that.  I wrote it a while back when I was a beginner so there is probably a better way, but this works.

```
try {
    InputStream is = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("sourceDatabaseFile.db");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("destinationDatabaseFile.db"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Another way would be to create the database using some Android code, and then have a (giant) class containing all the SQL statements to insert the data into the database.